# REDHAT machine + rsyslogd eating up 10+ GB

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, syslog, systemctl

we notice about this problem recently

we found that rsyslog service is eating memory and some times its up to 10G

we have different kind of redhat machines as version 7.6 and 7.9

is it possible to restart the service rsyslog automatically (by systemctl configuration) when for example service consuming more than 2 GIGA?

from the documentation I see that  ( service path -  `/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service` )

```
[Service]
MemoryLimit=2G
```

but not sure if we reached the memory limit ( 2G ) then service will restart automatically

here is example for what we want

in case rsyslog service consuming more then 2G, then service will restart as

```
systemctl restart rsyslog.service
```

if this above scenario can't implemented, then we hope to get other suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit the memory usage of the rsyslog service,
add memory limits to the file `/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.services`
under the `[Service]` section.

Example of allocating two gigabytes :

```
[Service]
MemoryAccounting=yes
MemoryCurrent=2G
MemoryLimit=2G
```

You may locate the unit file on any systemd distro with the command:

```
systemctl cat rsyslog.service
```

Reference :
[rsyslogd eating up 20+ GB (!) of RAM - what evidence to gather?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256813/rsyslogd-eating-up-20-gb-of-ram-what-evidence-to-gather/445043#445043)

Comment: the values - 8192000 ate in KB ?

Comment: if for example we reached the limit as 8192000KB , then what happened to the service ?

Comment: The memory sizes are specified in bytes. Usually the values can be suffixed with K, M, G or T, to specify Kilobytes, Megabytes, Gigabytes, or Terabytes (in base 1024). See [systemd.resource-control](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html).

Comment: if the size is in bytes then your example - 8192000 in giga means 0.007 GIGA , so I suggest to update you answer to 8192000000 byes that make Sens , the meaning of that that service will restart if service is consuming more then 8G

Comment: You may replace it by any number that fits your case.

Comment: yes you right but maybe oher users see your answer and it will be good for everyone to gives real size as 2G for example

Comment: No problem - done.